# Access ForeignKey set directly in template in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this simplified model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class ItemImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload_dir')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

An `Item` can have many `ItemImages`. I also have a template rendering the following data set from the view:

```
items = Item.objects.all()
```

So now I would want to do something like this in the template:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div>
    {{ item.name }}<br>
    <img src="{{ item.itemimage_set.all()[0] }}">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But obviously that's not possible. Not from the template directly, at least.

What is the proper way to get the equivalent of the first image inside the template?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
{% with item.itemimage_set.all|first as image %}
  <img src="{{ image.url }}" />
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: this is really a nice solution. i always forget about the with tag.

Comment: As of django 2.2 a neater way to write it can be `{% with image=item.itemimage_set.all|first %}` . Reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with).

Comment: It should be <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" />

Answer (score 19):

Or you could add a method to your `Item` model:

```
def get_first_image(self):
    return self.itemimage_set.all()[0]
```

and then call this method in your template:

```
{{ item.get_first_image }}
```

Or you could use:

```
{{ item.itemimage_set.all.0 }}
```

and to get the first image's url:

```
<img src="{{ item.itemimage_set.all.0.url }}">
```

Though if you need more flexibility (more than one picture in certain cases, etc.)  it's probably best to write a little templatetag.

Answer (score 9):

One possible way would be to iterate over all the `ItemImage`s like so:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div>
    {{ item.name }}<br>
    {% for image in item.itemimage_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, use the **related_name** in your models.

**models.py**

```
class Building(models.Model):
    address  = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Space(models.Model):
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    building  = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name="spaces_of_this_building")
```

**buildings.html**

```
{% for space in building.spaces_of_this_building.all %}
  {{ space.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: am I missing something: where is size defined? Is this built in, or is this another attribute of the Building model? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first picture from set you can do:

```
{% for item in item.image_set.all %}

{{if forloop.first }}
<img src="{{ item.url }}">
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

But i also love Andray solution with 'with'

Comment: This isn't a very elegant solution. `{% with %}` absolutely solves it.